# Show user info in a hovercard

Tags: custom-field, jquery, users, post-status, tooltip

I whant to display user info in a hovercard. I use a jquery plugin to for the hovercard. I call my file like this `<?php include 'includes/tooltip.php'; ?>` and this is my code from tooltip.php.

```
<div class="tip-info">
<?php if ($comment->user_id) {$userdata=get_userdata($comment->user_id); 
echo '<span>'. $userdata->display_name . '</span>';
echo '<span>'. $userdata->user_description .'</span>';
echo '<span>'. $userdata->twitter.'</span>';
echo '<span>'. $userdata->facebook .'</span>';
echo '<span>'. $userdata->google .'</span>';  
}?>
</div>
```

I use this code for extra fields in user profile google twitter etc..

```
function new_contactmethods( $contactmethods ) {
$contactmethods['twitter'] = 'Twitter'; // Add Twitter
$contactmethods['facebook'] = 'Facebook'; // Add Facebook
$contactmethods['google'] = 'google'; // Add google
unset($contactmethods['yim']); // Remove YIM
unset($contactmethods['aim']); // Remove AIM
unset($contactmethods['jabber']); // Remove Jabber
return $contactmethods;

}
add_filter('user_contactmethods','new_contactmethods',10,1);
```

The problem is with guests, their name is not displayed and the twitter, google, facebook fields are displayed for all users even for guest. Can any one tell me is my approach good. Is there another way to retrive user info ?

This is a photo whith the hovercard and what I whant to achive.
[Tip info](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/694/tipc.png/)

Comment: Is this question still relevant?

Answer (score -1):

[Jetpack](http://jetpack.me/) for Wordpress has hover cards for authors with gravatars. You could check for presence of data before echoing out the icon.

Comment: Yes but all users from my site have to make a gravata account, and this is not my interest.